# Removing Rows if Nan in Matab

Tags: matlab, row, nan

I have a table of 356x81 in matlab.
I want to remove rows if the contents of a certain 3 variables (out of the 18 variables) is `NaN`. In other words if any of these 3 variables has a `NaN` I want that row to be deleted. 
I found [a good example on another group](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/287085).

Only because my data is in a table format and I get problems with `isnan` I am using `ismissing` which works, but I do not know how to select the 3 specific variables. Right now if I use:

```
B = mydata(~any(ismissing(mydata),2),:);
```

Any row with `NaN` is removed.

Also I just can't figure out what the `2` is. I used it because it was in the example, but I have no idea what it is.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `2` is specifying that if *any* of the values in a row (the second dimension) are missing, then it will return `true`.

You can select just the columns you care about by using a cell arary of variable names as the column index into the table. Then we can check for missing values with `ismissing` and use `any` to determine if any of them are `NaN`.

```
toremove = any(ismissing(t(:, {'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3'})), 2);
subtable = t(~toremove,:);
```

Or if you want all three to be `NaN` in order for a row to be removed, we can use `and` instead

```
toremove = all(ismissing(t(:, {'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3'})), 2);
subtable = t(~toremove, :);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have R2016b, or can upgrade to it, you should check out the new [rmmissing function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmmissing.html):

```
x = rand(10,1); x(4) = NaN;
y = rand(10,1); y(2) = NaN;
z = rand(10,1); z(1) = NaN;
T = table(rand(10,1), x, y, z);
rmmissing(T, 'DataVariables', { 'x', 'y', 'z' });
```